# is it possible to make a looping statement in R wherein it will turn all column title of a dataframe into a variable & assign value basedon dataframe?

Tags: r

I have a large data frame. I want to make a looping statement wherein it will assign each column of the dataframe into a varible named after its column title.

In the code I created, when I type name[1] in the console before performing the looping statement, it shows the name of the column, for example "Company". However if I use it in a looping statement, instead of using "Company" as the variable name, it uses "name[1]".

This is the code I created

```
df = read.csv('fileName.csv')
a = 0
b = 1
while (a!=ncol(df)+1){
  name = colnames(df)
  name[b] = df[b]
  a = a+1
  b = b+1
}
```

e.g

```
col1     col2      col3
 1       pizza     coke
 2       burger    pepsi
 3       fries     sprite
```

Output:
When you type 'col1' on the console, its data will show. Instead of using df[1].

The variable will hold the data of the column based in the dataframe. Instead of manually coding

```
col1 = df[1]
col2 = df[2]
col3 = df[3]
```

it will be very exhaustive especially on the data frame I use that have almost 100 column title.

Comment: Can you show an example of `df`, and what your desired output is?

Comment: Hi, I already updated and show an example in my post. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `list2env` to convert each column of `df` to a separate object in the global environment.  This is normally not advised, but if you need to do it, you can do the following:

```
list2env(df,envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Running this on the above example frame (`df`), will result in three new objects in your global environment: `col1`, `col2`, and `col3`. For example:

```
> col2
[1] "pizza"  "burger" "fries"
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I somehow realized that this is actually not good because the naming convention is not consistent. Some of it has mix of upper and lower case. I think it will be better if I manually assign the column, which I only need, to a variable. Nevertheless, thank you so much. Ill still include this on my reporting tomorrow and tell them it's cons. It will also be a great opportunity for my colleagues to learn this matter. Thankss!